# How do I call custom.css in Prestashop 1.7?

Tags: css, prestashop-1.7

I'm new to Prestashop 1.7. There's a css that I need to overwrite. I've written the css codes on custom.css that comes with Prestashop. When I refreshed the site, the custom css did not apply. There was no link rel pointing to the file.

I'd like to ask how I can call the custom.css. There's a stylesheets.tpl but I'm not sure what code to write.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add my css to theme in prestashop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429109/add-my-css-to-theme-in-prestashop)

Comment: I can tell you for sure that `custom.css` is overwritten every time you update PrestaShop (with one click update). When I asked them why they push the whole setup for the minor updates (versus pushing only the modified files), they told me that they do so in order to block developers to upgrade the core.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add custom CSS & JS in the latest PrestaShop using setMedia() function which is located in the frontController as shown below:

**PATH : mainDir/classes/controller/FrontController.php**

```
public function setMedia()
    {
        $this->registerStylesheet('theme-main', '/assets/css/theme.css', ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 50]);
        $this->registerStylesheet('theme-custom', '/assets/css/custom.css', ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 1000]);

        if ($this->context->language->is_rtl) {
            $this->registerStylesheet('theme-rtl', '/assets/css/rtl.css', ['media' => 'all', 'priority' => 900]);
        }

        $this->registerJavascript('corejs', '/themes/core.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 0]);
        $this->registerJavascript('theme-main', '/assets/js/theme.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 50]);
        $this->registerJavascript('theme-custom', '/assets/js/custom.js', ['position' => 'bottom', 'priority' => 1000]);

        $assets = $this->context->shop->theme->getPageSpecificAssets($this->php_self);
        if (!empty($assets)) {
            foreach ($assets['css'] as $css) {
                $this->registerStylesheet($css['id'], $css['path'], $css);
            }
            foreach ($assets['js'] as $js) {
                $this->registerJavascript($js['id'], $js['path'], $js);
            }
        }

        // Execute Hook FrontController SetMedia
        Hook::exec('actionFrontControllerSetMedia', array());

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: i think this will be replaced when the PS is upgraded, better do it in the override/classes/controller/FrontController.php

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to copy it to assets/css folder of your theme